# VBscript and Excel: Opening and closing Excel objects - Arraylist preventing closing of object

Tags: excel, vbscript, arraylist

I've got a problem with a vbscript which creates Excel objects and reads from an Excel file.

The vbscript is executed from an Excel macro, and then creates and opens the Excel file and reads from it. The problem is that the Excel object isn't allways closed, even though I'm trying to to it.

Here's the code from the vbscript:

```
Set ExcelObject = createobject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObject.workbooks.open testWorkBookPath

Set testActionArray = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )

Function getTestsCaseActions (testsPath, esheet, row, col)
    Set my_sheet = ExcelObject.sheets.item(esheet)  

    tempArray = array(my_sheet.cells(row, col-2), "")
    testActionArray.Add tempArray

    Do While my_sheet.cells(row, col).Value <> ""
        tempArray = array(my_sheet.cells(row, col), my_sheet.cells(row+1, col))
        testActionArray.Add tempArray
        col = col+1
    Loop
End Function

getTestsCaseActions testWorkBookPath, testCaseSheet, 3, 4

ExcelObject.Quit
```

Now, if I run the above code and watch the process explorer, a new Excel process is spawned when the script is started, and then closes, as expected.

However, if I insert this code after running the function, before the ExcelObject.Quit line:

```
For Each ArrayItem in testActionArray
    IF ArrayItem(1) = "" Then
        Wscript.Echo ArrayItem(0)
    Else
        Wscript.Echo ArrayItem(0) & " -> " & ArrayItem(1)
    End If
Next

ExcelObject.Quit (STILL HERE)
```

then the spawned process does NOT quit, and the process list grows until Excel goes completely bananas.

I don't understand this; All the last bit of code does is loop through the ArrayList and print the contents. Why's not the process quitting?

EDIT: At seems that at least some of the Excel objects eventually disappear from the Process Explorer, but this takes about 20-30 minutes. And it's just a few of them - most are still there. At least my list at the moment has shrinked some, but there are still about 15 Excel processes running.

Also, suddenly this message appears:

```
File Now Available
'filename.xlsm ' is now available for editing. Choose Read-Write to open it for editing.
```

Comment: is it possible that Excel thinks the workbook is being edited? It maybe that Excel is trying to show the "do you want to save the changes" dialog. Try something like `dim book: for each book in ExcelObject.Workbooks: book.saved = true: next` before the quit.

Comment: It seems that the line posted by "oracle certified professional" helps. I'll keep it for a while and watch the process explorer.

Comment: oracle certified professional: As far as I can see, your suggestion works. If you add it as an answer, I'll give it the right credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to help. It doesn't completely remove all extra processes, but the number grows to five, then goes back to two, and so on. So it works pretty well.

```
dim book: for each book in ExcelObject.Workbooks: book.saved = true: next
```